# Trouble building schema for sqlfiddle

Tags: sql, sqlfiddle

I'm struggling to build a schema in sqlfiddle

On the left pane I enter this:

```
create table contacts (
  eid int(10),
  event_time timestamp
);

insert into contacts (
  eid, event_time)
values (
'991772', 2016-04-21 11:34:21,
'989628', 2016-04-17 02:19:57,
'985557', 2016-04-04 09:56:39,
'981920', 2016-03-30 11:03:12,
'981111', 2016-03-30 09:36:48,
'980094', 2016-03-29 12:55:28,
'979140', 2016-03-27 21:52:35,
'978732', 2016-03-24 11:37:14,
'977860', 2016-03-20 11:28:10,
'975730', 2016-03-09 12:46:51,
'972423', 2016-02-22 19:20:54,
'971998', 2016-02-21 10:51:25,
'971625', 2016-02-20 10:46:26,
'963732', 2016-02-02 04:18:31,
'962626', 2016-01-29 14:46:25,
'961310', 2016-01-26 15:13:10,
'958354', 2016-01-19 10:10:52,
'953278', 2016-01-06 00:15:52,
'925676', 2015-09-29 12:34:24,
'924938', 2015-09-26 01:48:35,
'917142', 2015-08-31 15:39:49,
'909758', 2015-08-18 02:30:53,
'906376', 2015-08-07 10:04:41,
'900640', 2015-07-21 04:41:35,
'891292', 2015-07-08 05:05:43,
'890300', 2015-07-05 04:40:30,
'882116', 2015-06-25 05:52:07,
'877398', 2015-06-25 05:15:39,
'867784', 2015-06-15 16:32:20,
'860696', 2015-06-03 16:28:48,
'856926', 2015-05-29 21:23:07,
'852006', 2015-05-20 09:41:51,
'850194', 2015-05-16 13:10:34,
'848416', 2015-05-12 20:14:36,
'835952', 2015-04-23 08:27:14,
'832550', 2015-04-16 10:52:45,
'829634', 2015-04-11 15:01:57,
'818734', 2015-03-19 10:17:37,
'817058', 2015-03-17 21:53:55,
'810288', 2015-03-05 12:07:58,
'796905', 2015-02-11 14:03:43,
'796795', 2015-02-11 12:00:18,
'792563', 2015-02-04 20:14:44,
'784219', 2015-01-22 17:58:27,
'780503', 2015-01-17 17:10:17,
'779761', 2015-01-16 12:39:20,
'776863', 2015-01-13 09:39:46,
'768407', 2014-12-30 17:48:36,
'764393', 2014-12-20 06:14:14,
'761639', 2014-12-16 05:49:39,
'760039', 2014-12-13 15:50:57,
'749431', 2014-11-24 23:59:41,
'731429', 2014-10-31 10:01:15,
'730813', 2014-10-30 12:16:18,
'730099', 2014-10-29 13:15:06,
'730087', 2014-10-29 13:13:36,
'727465', 2014-10-26 15:26:23,
'723055', 2014-10-20 19:06:02,
'722543', 2014-10-20 11:32:35,
'720637', 2014-10-16 09:56:47,
'717573', 2014-10-04 16:20:39,
'708611', 2014-08-30 13:57:58,
'697237', 2014-07-16 11:55:10,
'690235', 2014-06-25 14:32:40,
'473417', 2014-04-25 17:01:54,
'469875', 2014-04-15 12:57:28,
'462433', 2014-03-26 12:42:22,
'457409', 2014-03-18 15:58:36,
'447423', 2014-02-04 22:06:54,
'440453', 2014-01-09 18:16:34,
'432621', 2013-12-03 02:47:46,
'430535', 2013-11-21 17:42:30,
'427727', 2013-11-10 11:40:51,
'426913', 2013-11-07 10:51:07,
'426619', 2013-11-07 07:47:36,
'419563', 2013-10-08 12:37:50,
'414241', 2013-09-12 14:22:26,
'413933', 2013-09-11 11:52:19,
'375765', 2013-08-14 16:04:44,
'375581', 2013-08-13 21:52:22,
'374911', 2013-08-10 20:05:32,
'366801', 2013-07-15 17:06:59,
'365017', 2013-07-07 15:08:55,
'363677', 2013-07-01 09:02:17,
'359695', 2013-06-12 15:11:15,
'358785', 2013-06-08 10:18:42,
'337077', 2013-03-13 09:32:20,
'333823', 2013-02-25 13:44:05,
'329941', 2013-02-06 18:58:11,
'322941', 2013-01-11 21:36:52,
'318841', 2012-12-19 15:52:45,
'316839', 2012-12-07 19:10:44,
'312725', 2012-11-15 01:32:20,
'298613', 2012-10-02 20:16:43,
'291381', 2012-09-12 06:39:17,
'207513', 2012-06-27 12:20:49,
'206073', 2012-06-20 17:08:15,
'202913', 2012-06-04 11:00:30,
'201447', 2012-05-24 16:08:35,
'200503', 2012-05-19 05:25:29,
'199643', 2012-05-14 20:58:55,
'197854', 2012-04-28 08:29:11,
'190369', 2012-03-27 13:32:08,
'183708', 2012-01-21 11:18:05,
'179191', 2011-12-05 17:44:59,
'177536', 2011-11-29 19:47:49,
'175989', 2011-11-10 23:10:56,
'175676', 2011-11-07 08:33:45,
'175260', 2011-11-02 00:10:39,
'173520', 2011-10-19 02:03:41,
'169358', 2011-09-01 06:55:15,
'169230', 2011-08-30 15:18:45,
'165594', 2011-07-14 22:48:31,
'165163', 2011-07-09 15:24:12,
'165044', 2011-07-07 17:14:26,
'164944', 2011-07-06 16:38:20,
'163117', 2011-06-16 13:05:36,
'161112', 2011-06-16 11:28:26,
'160565', 2011-06-16 11:02:05,
'158080', 2011-06-16 09:56:59,
'153493', 2011-06-16 08:02:16,
'153479', 2011-06-16 08:02:14,
'150105', 2011-06-16 06:25:55,
'133281', 2011-05-27 18:30:30,
'132279', 2011-05-25 10:43:22,
'132160', 2011-05-25 09:50:21,
'121644', 2011-02-26 05:14:51,
'119116', 2011-01-10 21:43:16,
'113875', 2010-11-20 22:09:57,
'94921', 2010-07-06 15:51:11,
'91807', 2010-04-29 20:07:32,
'84052', 2009-11-06 04:44:27,
'79916', 2009-09-12 20:01:35,
'77402', 2009-08-07 16:14:04,
'73684', 2009-07-20 02:47:39,
'71592', 2009-06-30 00:51:53,
'71308', 2009-06-25 09:39:00,
'68566', 2009-05-29 09:27:41,
'36116', 2008-12-23 19:38:07,
'33714', 2008-12-04 08:03:17,
'25979', 2008-07-02 06:21:05,
'20722', 2008-03-10 22:08:07,
'16791', 2008-01-09 13:10:38,
'16535', 2008-01-03 12:10:27,
'7961', 2007-02-26 13:30:04,
'6370', 2007-01-22 10:02:35
);
```

When I hit build I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '11:34:21, '989628', 2016-04-17 02:19:57, '985557', 2016-04-04
>   09:56:39, '981920'' at line 4

I tried wrapping the timestamp in quotes but also received errors.

How do I get this table built into sqlfiddle?

Comment: I just did this and worked fine for 1 row - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cd59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> **INSERT** statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7b25/1/0)

```
insert into contacts (eid, event_time) values
('991772', '2016-04-21 11:34:21'),
('989628', '2016-04-17 02:19:57'),
('985557', '2016-04-04 09:56:39'),
...
('6370',  '2007-01-22 10:02:35');
```

Additionally, you have to put the `event_time` values in `''`.

Comment: aha! Thank you so much